# Mod shows up with OP background when viewing deleted comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools

As they say, a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: screenshot]

The moderator here is not the original poster, but on the comments by the aforementioned OP, his name has the OP background. On the other comments, he (correctly) doesn't.

Comment: Delete ALL THE THINGS! \nn/

Comment: @ColeJohnson because it's on [Meta.Scifi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/), which has a dark color scheme.

Comment: It's good Meta.SciFi uses a different background color, now. `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno it doesn't. That color is the standard translucent red/pink deleted comments color over the dark gray M.SFF background.

Comment: [Reproduced](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nFL65.png) on Literature.

Answer (score 12):

I just encountered this on The Workplace (and then looked for it on Mi Yodeya to verify it's cross-site), then started to post the bug report and found this question.  This is new behavior for me (I'm pretty sure!), though the OP reports that it's been broken on SciFi since this bug was reported in 2014.

Here are some screen shots with a little less eyeball-bleed:

The Workplace:

[image: Workplace example]

Mi Yodeya:
[image: Mi Yodeya example]

Comment: Never went away for scifi, might have gone away for a while with the redesign that went out for most sites.

Comment: @Kevin hmm, ok.  I don't *think* it's been like this all along on my sites, but maybe it has and I was ignoring it until coming back after a week on mobile and seeing it fresh.  FWIW, Mi Yodeya doesn't have the new design yet (but The Workplace does).

Answer (score 8):

This has been fixed. Going forward, only the question asker's comments (and "deleted by" records) will have the added background.

Answer (score 2):

This actually seems to be even more important now, because it seems to control the presence of “undelete”:

- comments deleted by former moderators can’t be undeleted
- comments deleted by flags meeting the criteria for automatic deletion can’t be undeleted

I’ve run into this with a few invalid auto-deletions that I couldn’t reverse.